# How to remove white space at the bottom of the webpage

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm currently working on my portfolio website using `BootStrap v5` which I'm still developing and I'm facing an issue with responsiveness. The issue with my webpage is that there is a blank space when viewed in `iPad Pro`, `Nexus 10` and `Kindle Fire HDX` whose heights are `1280px`, `1280px` and `1360px` respectively.

**Screenshots of portfolio website in 3 devices**

**Kindle Fire HDX**

[image]

**Nexus 10**

[image]

**iPad Pro**

[image]

As shown, there is a blank white space which I'm still struggling to remove.

**Styles.css**

```
@media (orientation: potrait) and (min-height: 1280px){
  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
}
```

I've tried using `media-query` in `CSS` which didn't work.

**index.html**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
```

I have added the `meta` tag which worked for most devices except the 3 devices specified above

Is there a method to solve this problem? I've read similar threads akin to responsiveness but to no avail.

Comment: I think you'll need to add your html, content removed, along with the css or everyone will be guessing

Comment: Is 'sticky footer' what you're looking for? Or...I don't think the problem is size of the device, it's size of the page when there is not much content on it. You might have to look up how to keep the footer at the bottom of a short page.

Comment: So in this case I should add more to compensate the white space?

Comment: @wazz Thanks brother. I have solved it by adding more content to my website

Comment: Check if you gave any margin or padding or something.

Comment: @KarambirSingh I didn't add `margin-bottom` to my `footer` tag. It's just that white space is formed due to less content in the website as suggested by @waaz.